# Is there a way to of getting part of a dataframe from an azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, hdf5

So I have a a lot of data in an Azure blob storage. Each user can upload some cases and the end result can be represented as a series of panda dataframes. Now I want to be able to display some of this data on our site, but the files are several hundreds of MB and there is no need to download all of it. What would be the best way to get part of the df?

I can make a folder structure in each blob storage containing the different columns in each df and perhaps a more more compact summery of the columns but I would like to keep it in one file if possible.

I could also set up a database containing the info but I like the structure as it is - completely separated in cases.

Originally I thought I could do it in hdf5 but it seems that I need to download the entire file from the blob storage to my API backend before I can run my python code on it. I would prefer if I could keep the hdf5 files and get the parts of the columns from the blob storage directly but as far as I can see that is not possible.

I am thinking this is something that has been solved a million times before but it is a bit out of my domain so I have not been able to find a good solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `BlobClient` of the Azure Python SDK. The [download_blob method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-download-blob) might suit your needs. Use `chunks()` to get an iterator which allows you to iterate of over the file in chunks. You can also set other parameters to assure that a chunk doesn't exceed a set size.

Comment: That will load the df into a stream. I guess I would have to structure the hdf5 file in the right way. Otherwise there is the query_blob which might be helpful. I will look more into the site and see what is the best choice.

Comment: Yes I would do that. The docs are well written imo.